# Making sense of the proof : The set $\{s_n(x)=(2/\pi)^{1/2} \sin nx:n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is an orthonormal basis in $L^2[0,\pi]$- Rynne- Youngson

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

The following theorem is from the book by Bryan P. Rynne, Martin A. Youngson - Linear Functional Analysis-Springer (2008)

**I am having trouble understanding the proof of theorem 3.56.**

[image]

**I'fd like to determine if there is an error in the book and find a proof of the statement.**

**If the book is right, since the author says he is just sketching it, could someone write the missing details? Specifically, explaining this 2 points:**

-Why do we need to approximate f, which is an $L^2[0,\pi]$ function with another $L^2[0,\pi]$ function ($f_\delta$). Is the author sugesting that the set of $\{f_\delta, f\in L^2[0,\pi]\}$ is dense in $L^2[0,\pi]$? Even if that is true I don't see the point of this construction

-Why is $f_\delta/\sin(x) \in L^2[0,\pi]$? This doesn't seem correct. For instance if $f(x)=c=$constant ,then $f \in L^2[0,\pi]$ and $f_\delta/\sin(x)$ seems to go to $\infty$ at $x=\pi$, so if it is not even bounded how could it be in$ L^2[0,\pi]$? And how does this help with the proof?

**If the book is wrong, prove it and make a correct proof. Notice that we can not use as others do that the set formed by the union of $C$ and $S$ in theorems 3.56 and 3.54 is an orthornormal set, since the book proves that later using them**

For reference I provide  also theorem 3.54 below which is supposed to be similar, yet I haven't been able to make sense of theorem 3.56 by following theorem 3.54.

[image]

Note:

-theorem 1.40: density of $C[a,b]$ in $L^p[a,b]$

-theorem 1.62: Stone-Weierstrass' theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is an error.  We should define
$$ f_\delta(x) = \cases{0 &if $x\in[0,\delta]\cup[\pi-\delta,\pi]$\cr f(x) &if $x\in(\delta,\pi-\delta)$. } $$
Second, the set
$$\{f_\delta:f \in L^2_{\mathbb R}[0,\pi], \delta>0\} = \bigcup_{\delta>0} \{f_\delta:f \in L^2_{\mathbb R}[0,\pi]\} $$
is dense in $L^2_{\mathbb R}[0,\pi]$.

Comment: thanks, bounty hunter! :)

Comment: @J.C.VegaO You wouldn't mind upvoting me as well?  Then I get closer to a silver medal for real analysis.